# Android preferences - what is the difference?

Tags: android, android-preferences, android-sharedpreferences

What is the difference, when I get preferences as:

```
PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(getBaseContext());
```

and

```
getPreferences(Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
```

Answer (score 24, accepted):

```
PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(getBaseContext());
```

Will provide an access to a preferences file that is global for the whole application package ; any activity can access the preferences (internaly, the xml file holding the preferences will be named `your.application.package_preferences.xml`).

```
contextInstance.getPreferences(Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
```

Will provide preferences only for the contextInstance class: only instances of the context's class can access these preferences (said your package is still `your.application.package` and you're in `your.application.package.foo.MyActivity`, internaly the preferences file is `foo.MyActivity.xml`).

Comment: Well, you explained it better than me. Thumbs up!

Comment: Thanks, OcuS. Could you please also clarify if I use `.getDefaultSharedPreferences(getBaseContext())`, will other applications be able to edit this value?

Comment: No, because `getDefaultSharedPreferences(Context context)` will give you preferences in `Context.MODE_PRIVATE` (according to http://android.git.kernel.org/?p=platform/frameworks/base.git;a=blob;f=core/java/android/preference/PreferenceManager.java;h=e44a0907d20916613f02843291deef9483433052;hb=HEAD#l347 ). May be you could try something like what is explained in this thread's last post http://groups.google.com/group/android-developers/browse_thread/thread/6f1a12fffd60a824 . Never tried myself, hope it helps anyway.